# Why does one ostream << overload work but the other doesn't?

Tags: c++

I have to use some overloaded << ostream operators for a project, and I got the first one to work properly for date, but the one that is from my other class seems to be giving me some problems and I can't figure it out for the life of me. It doesn't give me any errors, it just doesn't work the proper way and prints out, which almost looks like a memory address instead. Also, when I run the debugger, it doesn't seem to "step into" the ostream overload function like it does for the date version.

This is in my main, which is initializing correctly my Movie object

```
    list<int> time1{1000, 1200, 1400, 1600};
    list<int> time2{ 1100, 1300, 1500, 1700 };

    Cinema cinema;
    Movie * movie1 = new Movie("Superman", 1988, 11, 8);
    cout << movie1;

    cinema.addMovie(movie1, time1);
```

And this is my Date class

```
class Date 
{
    public: 
        Date(int = 0, int = 0, int = 0);
        //…. 
        // other as appropriate 
        bool operator < (Date&);
        bool operator == (Date &); 
        friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, const Date &); 
        friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, Date &);

    private:
        int day, month, year;
};
```

And this is my Movie Class

```
class Movie 
{
    public:
        Movie(const string & name, int yyyy, int mm, int dd) : name(name), releaseDate(Date(yyyy, mm, dd)) {};

        const Date getReleaseDate(); 
        // other? 
        bool operator < (Movie& r);
        bool operator == (Movie &); 
        Movie & operator ++ (); 
        friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, Movie &); 
        friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, const Movie &); 
        const string getName();

    private: 
        Movie() = default; 
        const Date releaseDate; 
        string name; 
        int rating = 0;
};
```

These are my Date ostream << overloads which works fine

```
ostream & operator << (ostream& os, Date & dt)
{
    os << dt.month << "/" << dt.day << "/" << dt.year << "\n";
    return os;
}

//////

ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const Date & dt)
{
    os << dt.month << "/" << dt.day << "/" << dt.year << "\n";
    return os;
}
```

And these are my Movie ones, which don't throw any errors, they just print out, what looks to be a memory address  but i'm not sure

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & os, Movie & mo)
{
    os << mo.getName() << " released: " << mo.releaseDate << " rated " << mo.rating << "\n";
    return os;
}

///////////

ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const Movie & mo)
{
    os << mo.name << " released: " << mo.releaseDate << " rated " << mo.rating << "\n";
    return os;
}
```

What is the difference why one works and the other doesn't?

Comment: Not your problem but you don't need to have two overloads, you only need the `const` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple error

```
cout << movie1;
```

should be

```
cout << *movie1;
```

The moral is, don't use pointers needlessly.